# Как перенести файлы на FTP сервер?

Tags: python, sftp, ftp-сервер

Во первых у меня получилось использовать только sftp подключение поэтому выбрал данную бибилиотеку, проблема в том что при переносе файлов на FTP данный код срабатывает вот так

## [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW89s.png)

то есть перед названием файла добавляется .\ и нарушается вложенность

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None   
myHostname = ""
myUsername = ""
myPassword = ""

with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print ("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
  
    localpath = 'E:/site/'

    remotepath = 'web/website.com/public_html/'

    sftp.put_r(localpath, remotepath)
```

Comment: Срабатывает так - это как? Опишите ожидаемое поведение

Comment: название 1й папки просто en а не .\en, далее папка assets вложенная папка в en

Comment: Ну так .\en - скорее всего не название папки а просто относительный путь

Comment: как раз таки при переносе он добавляет .\ к названию папки

Comment: ftp не имеет никакого отношения к sftp, кроме похожих буковок в названии

Comment: спасибо, очень помог отвечаю

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434941/pysftp-vs-paramiko

Comment: та же проблема, библиотека из коробки с кодом в 1 строчку с оффсайта не работает, печально. вы нашли решение?